# how to load a .pb vgg16 trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, pickle

I am trying to load a trained model for image beautification saved at local device through the code below:

```
# load network
network_pkl = misc.locate_network_pkl(args.results_dir)
print('Loading network from "%s"...' % network_pkl)
G, D, Gs = misc.load_network_pkl(args.results_dir, None)



def load_network_pkl(run_id_or_result_subdir_or_network_pkl, snapshot=None):
    return load_pkl(locate_network_pkl(run_id_or_result_subdir_or_network_pkl, snapshot))


def load_pkl(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
         return legacy.LegacyUnpickler(file, encoding='latin').load()

def save_pkl(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

and I got this error as below:

> Initializing TensorFlow... Loading network from
>   "C:\Users\wissa\Desktop\Out-source-projects/vgg_tf.pb"... Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "beautify_image.py", line 46, in
>   
>       G, D, Gs = misc.load_network_pkl(args.results_dir, None)   File "C:\Users\wissa\Desktop\Out-source-projects\Beholder-GAN-master\misc.py",
>   line 674, in load_network_pkl
>       return load_pkl(locate_network_pkl(run_id_or_result_subdir_or_network_pkl,
>   snapshot))   File
>   "C:\Users\wissa\Desktop\Out-source-projects\Beholder-GAN-master\misc.py",
>   line 436, in load_pkl
>       return pickle.load(file)
>   _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ', ' '.

could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: .pb sounds like a protobuf file, not a pickled network. Have you tried https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm trying to solve it, but the problem is i'm using anaconda 3 and they haven't supported tensorflow 2.1 yet. So how far i can't use tf.saved_model.load :-( so idk i'm trying to figure it out.